# logo redesign, show original?

Tags: logo, branding

I am putting my portfolio together. Should I show the original logo that I redesigned on that page? Is it necessary? I have seen it both ways and would like to know your opinion

Answer (score 1):

This question is likely to be closed as too "opinion-based". (yes, I voted to close it based on that as well).

It really all boils down to personal preference and design of your specific presentation (portfolio). There's no hard and fast rule about this, and in many cases there may not be any preexisting logo to show.

Many web sites choose to show "case studies" which detail the processes of creating something - based in redesign or from inception. But there are an equal number of web sites that don't bother with this approach.

My *opinion* is the only area where there may be a specific desire for such items is during interviews in person. Otherwise, people just want to see what you created, not where you started.

For an in-person interview, I find having a couple (non-portfolio) pieces on hand to show preexisting designs which were improved upon can be helpful. But I, personally, would never make them *actually* part of a portfolio and would never include them in any portfolio "drop off".